# single-step simulation in tensorflow RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a RNN controller, which takes the current state of the plant as the input to the RNN, and generates the output as the controlling signal . After executing the control, the updated plant state is fed back to the RNN as the input of next time step. In this looping, the input sequence is stacked step by step, rather than all given in advance. 
For now, no training is involved. Only the single-step forward simulation is needed. 
So a tensorflow RNN operation that can do this one-step RNN output is what I'm looking for.

```
input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, len_seq,8])
```

I defined two kinds of input: `Input_data` for the `batch_size` sequences of input,  and `input_single` for the input of current time step.

```
input_single = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 1, 8])
action_gradient = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, len_seq, dimAction])
num_hidden = 24    
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)
state_single = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
(output_single, state_single) = cell(input_single, state_single)
weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, dimAction]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[dimAction]))
y_single = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(output_single, weight) + bias)
```

The network is read out in two ways: `y_single` for each time step, and `y_seq` for the whole minibatch of the input.

```
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, input_data, dtype=tf.float32)
y_seq = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(outputs, weight) + bias)
```

Comment: Yes, I have problems with the code. Inserted are some lines. I tried to make an input variable of one-step input. When using the "input_single",   it came up with a TypeError: 'Variable' object is not iterable.

Comment: you will need to provide some more code, how is `input_single` defined? Also, why don't you use `cell.zero_state(1,tf.float32)` for `state_single`?

Comment: @martianwars The input single is defined as a placeholder with the shape of `[1, 1, input_size]`. The reason I did not use the `cell.zero_state(1,tf.float32)` for `state_single` initialization, again, is the concern that the state is not a sequence but only has one time-step.

Comment: `zero_state` doesn't return a sequence, it returns a single `state` of size `[batch size x state size]`

Comment: It returns a `batch_size` number of states that specify each initial state of the `batch_size` number of sequence?

Comment: No, the `batch_size` is all fed together and represents a single run. You need to put that in a `for` loop to make a sequence

Comment: The code here will help you https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply calling your `tf.rnn.LSTMCell` object once. Make sure you put correct arguments. Something like this will help you,

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)
input_single = tf.ones([batch_size, input_size])
state_single = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
(output_single, state_single) = cell(input_single, state_single)
```

Have a look at the documentation for [`RNNCell.__call__()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/294442996b2aeff00b1bfdc7e7169f7cb35bbf3d/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L89) for more details on what the shape of `input_single` and `state_single` should be, if you have a good reason not to use `cell.zero_state()`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the above code. And I put more of my code in the question box. Hope it better describes my problem.

Comment: accepted. too bad i don't have reputation to upvote.